# Angular JS & Node Webkit Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I am building an app using node-webkit and Angular-JS and I am having the following problem:

The app **works fine in chrome**, but when compiled into node, most routes lead to an file-listing page. If I run the external debugger, I don't get an error in the console (using chrome devtools), however I do notice that when I click a link it takes me to "file://C:/#/link" rather than "file://C:/subfolder/subfolder2/#/link" like it should.

Do I need to tell node-webkit to set the correct base-url?

A simple example of my setup is:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Main Page</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body ng-cloak ng-controller="ClockController">
<div id="nav">
<a href="/#/link/1">Link 1</a>
<a href="/#/link/2">Link 2</a>
<a href="/#/link/3">Link 3</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes JS:

```
"use strict";

angular.module('app')
.config([
    '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
            })                
            .when('/link/:linkid', {

                    templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                        return 'link_'+ $stateParams.linkid +'.html';
                    }
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
      }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with having a base URL if you plan to run it in multiple places. Also, using `./` instead of `/` (which goes to the root of wherever you are) might work.

Comment: Which one, the base url or `./`?

Comment: I tried setting <base href="./"> and it didn't help. There isn't another base url I can set as I can';t know the structure of someones pc when they run the app. Maybe node-webkit can provide the path through js? There must be some standard way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you question right, but I think process.execPath is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

first issue is that your using `$routeProvider` from the `ng` module, but your grabbing the parameters from the `$stateParams` service which i believe is from  angular-ui-router, if you want the parameters when your using `$routeProvider` grab them from the `$routeParams` service.

next to fix your issue with loading the templates just define them in script tags in your index.html file using the template name as the script tag id like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <!-- your template html goes here -->
</script>
```

and for the links, i would put `href="#"` and then something like `ng-click="changeRoute('/home')"`

then in a run function define that on your `$rootScope`

```
app.run(runFunc);

runFunc.$inject = ['$rootScope','$location','$route'];

function runFunc($rootScope,$location,$route){
    $rootScope.changeRoute = changeRoute;

    function changeRoute(route){
        $location.path(route);
        $route.reload();
    }
}
```

that should work for you